# ADFS token-signing cert per relying party

Tags: certificate, adfs

Server 2012 R2, if I set up a cert on the encryption tab of a relying party, would that relying party use that cert for token-signing instead of the shared token-signing cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - that certificate is for encrypting the token. This is a per RP certificate. This is added security - effectively encrypted twice - this plus SSL.

The token signing certificate is ADFS wide.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the answer, just wanted to make sure :)